# Executing Visual Studio Test Task on Azure Pipelines: Updating DontShowUI to 1 failed due to exception

Tags: testing, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

I am executing the Visual Studio Test Task on Azure Pipelines. The agent runs on a Windows Server 2019 Datacenter, however the tests run within a docker container.

Everything works fine and all tests execute, but I see this warning in the output:

> [warning]Updating HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI to 1 failed due to exception :
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

I had a look into the registry and there is actually no value "DontShowUI" in this path. I tried to add it and set the value to 1, but the warning still appears.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: What version of the test task? It looks like VsTestV2 uses Typescript to access the registry and I wouldn't expect this error. You can use `reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\DontShowUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 1` in a script step to force the value.

Comment: I am using VsTestV2, and I have added the value manually in the regedit. Still the warning shows up. :(

Comment: How about run your test on the machine where your private agent exists directly without Azure decops, so that we could narrow the scope of this issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @AlexI no, the warning still shows up. However since its just a warning its not high priority in my task list. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same warning with

```
Task         : Visual Studio Test
Version      : 2.153.9
```

And correct command to update registry to suppress the warning is next:

```
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting" /v DontShowUI /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```